# Performance looping, using this in which attribute or not

Tags: javascript, performance, loops

i'm very interest in performance, and i would like to know how should i use in this case.

This:

```
var Mapper;

Mapper = function() {
  this.files = this.files;
  this.result = [];
  return this.each_file();
};

Mapper.prototype.each_file = function() {
  this.length = this.files.length;
  this.index = 0;
  while (this.index < this.length) {
    this.result.push(this.get_info(this.file[this.index]));
    this.index++;
  }
  return this.result;
};

Mapper.prototype.get_info = function(file) {
  var info;
  return info = {
    name: file,
    exist: null,
    status: [],
    type: 'pdf'
  };
};

module.exports = Mapper;
```

Or this:
    var Mapper;

```
Mapper = function() {
  this.files = this.files;
  this.result = [];
  return this.each_file();
};

Mapper.prototype.each_file = function() {
  var index, length;
  length = this.files.length;
  index = 0;
  while (index < length) {
    this.result.push(this.get_info(this.file[index]));
    index++;
  }
  return this.result;
};

Mapper.prototype.get_info = function(file) {
  var info;
  return info = {
    name: file,
    exist: null,
    status: [],
    type: 'pdf'
  };
};

module.exports = Mapper;
```

Explaining:

I am doing a while looping to get information from files, in the first code, i'm using this in ALL properties, and in the second one i'm using this in just a few. I would like to know which one is the smarter, better for performance issues.

OBS: I'm looping for more than 3.000 files.

Comment: 3000 times is not enough to notice a minor difference such as the two versions.

Comment: You can use some tools like http://www.broofa.com/Tools/JSLitmus/ for this kind of test. But in that case the difference will not be really notified

Comment: I don't think it matters for performance. But storing helper variables in the instance seems wrong. I would use the 2nd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking whether using variable from `this` or variable in the local function scope has any significant impact on performance then the answer is no. However, length and indices are really temporal variables that belongs to local function scope, so your second implementation makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well from performance point of view I don't think you will see any difference. I would say that option 2 is potentially faster due to the fact how object property gets found, but again this "faster" is so small that you may even not wary about it.
But from code style/best practices point of view option 2 is better